# Where is my chrome shortcut being saved to?

Tags: chrome, desktop-shortcuts

I can create a shortcut in Chrome with `More tools > Create shortcut`. For Windows the documentation suggests that this will create some kind of file on the Desktop which users can click to open the shortcut. On Linux, not running a desktop environment, I see no such files. Yet, I would really like to have a script which I could run to open my shortcut. How can I do this?

I tried looking in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME/chromium` but couldn't find anything promising. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I figured out that I needed to be looking for a file ending in `.desktop`. Then I searched my home folder for new `.desktop` files. I did find one with a cryptic name including the prefixed string `chrome`. Opening it up in a text editor I found the title matched my shortcut and there was a shell command for starting up my shortcut.

Comment: Try in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity: That was exactly where it was.

Comment: For me, the location was `~/Desktop`